# R POST API request with httr returns bad requests

Tags: r, api, post, rcurl, httr

Would like to implement the following `POST` request with `curl` with the `httr` package in R

```sh
curl 'https://api.openfigi.com/v2/mapping' \
--request POST \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '[{"idType":"ID_WERTPAPIER","idValue":"851399","exchCode":"US"}]'
```

Based on this [Git issue](https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/159) I tried:

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(rjson)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rjson'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:jsonlite':
#> 
#>     fromJSON, toJSON
library(httr)

url = 'https://api.openfigi.com/v2/mapping'

body1 = list(
  idType = jsonlite::unbox('ID_WERTPAPIER'),
  idValue = jsonlite::unbox('851399'),
  exchCode = jsonlite::unbox('US')
)
r = httr::POST(url, body = body1, encode = 'json', verbose())

body2 = rjson::toJSON(list(
  idType = "ID_WERTPAPIER",
  idValue = "851399",
  exchCode = "US"
))

r = httr::POST(url, body = body2, encode = "form", verbose())
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

But both are bad requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work if you just translate the curl. Is that sufficient?

```
require(httr)

headers = c(
  `Content-Type` = 'application/json'
)

data = '[{"idType":"ID_WERTPAPIER","idValue":"851399","exchCode":"US"}]'

r <- httr::POST(url = 'https://api.openfigi.com/v2/mapping', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data)
print(r$status_code)
```

Comment: if i may ask: Do you know how it is that we dont have to use `encode = "raw"` as suggested in the docu `?POST`?

Comment: @ThanksGuys What is _docu ?POST_ ?

Comment: the documentation that appears if you enter `?POST` in the console (in R). I should have provided the direct link actually: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.4.1/topics/POST, sry.